# How to create iphone app to call via wifi/3g (VoIP)?

Tags: iphone, voip, sip, openurl

I want to developed an iphone app, allow to call via wifi/3g.
Please provide me example statement to:

How to Client send request to sip provider?
How to Sip provider establish a connection to other Client?

thanks,

Comment: This involves many 10's of thousands of lines of source code, too much to post here.  Start reading.

Comment: thanks hotpaw2. can you post link for reading or download source code?

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely take a look at this project: [pjsip](http://www.pjsip.org/) that will give you a strong starting point for your application.